# Why can we create a static class like Math which is already in csharp

Tags: c#

I have created a class in csharp named Math but it is already in csharp. But we can't create two or more than static class with a same name. I want to know what is the reason for creating another static class like Math

```
using System;

namespace apps
{
    public static class Math
    {
        public static float sqrt(float a)
        {
            return a * a * a;
        }
    }
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(Math.sqrt(9));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's in a different namespace, so that should work. You have to specify the namespace, because you will get a "ambiguous symbol" warning with the above code.

Answer (score 1):

Because you have another namespace for your class.
`namespace apps`

The original `Math` - class is in the namespace `System`